# can't drop or delete columns in dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

when I try to delete column "Header=" from my data frame:

```
#import data
for path in filepaths:
    df = pd.read_csv(r"{}".format(path), header=6, sep="delimiter", engine="python")
#delete column "Header="
    del df['Header=']
```

I get this error:

```
    File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
      File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
      File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
      File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
    KeyError: 'Header='
```

And when I try the drop function:

```
for path in filepaths:
    df = pd.read_csv(r"{}".format(path), header=6, sep="delimiter", engine="python")
    df.drop("Header=", axis=1, inplace=True)
```

I get this error:

```
raise KeyError(f"{labels[mask]} not found in axis")
KeyError: "['Header='] not found in axis"
```

from these errors, it seems that I don't have a column named "Header=", but when I run this code:

```
for path in filepaths:
    df = pd.read_csv(r"{}".format(path), header=6, sep="delimiter", engine="python")
    all_files.append(df)

print(df.columns)
```

I get this output:

```
Index(['Header=,"PK","RT","Area Pct","Library/ID","Ref","CAS","Qual"'], dtype='object')
```

In which "Header=" is one of the column names

finally when I printing the head of the data looks like this:

```
print(df.head)

<bound method NDFrame.head of    Header=,"PK","RT","Area Pct","Library/ID","Ref","CAS","Qual"
0   1=,  1,  1.3671,27.3306,"Nitrogen oxide (N2O) ...          
1   2=,  2,  2.5023, 0.2947,"Methyl-d3 1-Dideuteri...          
2   3=,  3,  4.1156, 0.6791,"Heptane, 2,4-dimethyl...          
3   4=,  4,  4.6653, 0.3038,"Octane, 4-methyl- (CA...          
4   5=,  5,  4.7131,32.2856,"Acetamide, N,N-dimeth...          
5   6=,  6,  6.1590,28.7519,"Phenol (CAS) $$ Izal ...          
6   7=,  7,  6.3144, 0.1824,"Acetamide, 2-chloro- ...          
7   8=,  8,  6.8044, 5.7176,"l-Limonene $$ Cyclohe...          
8   9=,  9,  7.0911, 1.1867,"DECANE, 3,7-DIMETHYL-...          
9   10=, 10,  7.1509, 0.3323,"(R,R)-3,8-Dimethylde...          
10  11=, 11,  7.5811, 0.6304,"DECANE, 3,7-DIMETHYL...          
11  12=, 12,  7.6408, 0.1889,"Decane, 4-methyl- (C...          
12  13=, 13,  8.0949, 0.2466,"6-Aza-5,7,12,14-tetr...          
13  14=, 14,  9.4094, 0.5843,"Hexadecane, 2,6,10,1...          
14  15=, 15,  9.8038, 0.3497,"2,4-di(trimethylsilo...          
15  16=, 16,  9.8396, 0.1937,"Eicosane (CAS) $$ n-...          
16  17=, 17, 11.2736, 0.5516,"TETRADECAMETHYLCYCLO...          
17  18=, 18, 11.4290, 0.1900,"Phenol, 2,4-bis(1,1-...          >
```

Comment: Could you provide a few rows of your dataframe and explain what you want to achieve with the corresponding ouput? Here's a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that can help you get started. To delete a column, use the [df.drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html?highlight=drop#pandas.DataFrame.drop) method with the `columns` you wan to get rid of

Comment: the error is obvious, `Header=` does not exist in your dataframe, try `print(df.columns)` and inspect the columns

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh  `print(df.head)`  `<bound method NDFrame.head of    Header=,"PK","RT","Area Pct","Library/ID","Ref","CAS","Qual"
0   1=,  1,  1.3671,27.3306,"Nitrogen oxide (N2O) ...          
1   2=,  2,  2.5023, 0.2947,"Methyl-d3 1-Dideuteri...          
2   3=,  3,  4.1156, 0.6791,"Heptane, 2,4-dimethyl...          
3   4=,  4,  4.6653, 0.3038,"Octane, 4-methyl- (CA...          
4   5=,  5,  4.7131,32.2856,"Acetamide, N,N-dimeth...          
5   6=,  6,  6.1590,28.7519,"Phenol (CAS) $$ Izal ...          `

Comment: Please update the post. Your comment is hard to read.

Comment: @Manakin  when doing this I get this output:  `Index(['Header=,"PK","RT","Area Pct","Library/ID","Ref","CAS","Qual"'], dtype='object')` 

in which Header= is a column.

Comment: i see `Header=,"PK"` not `Header=` try `df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.contains('Header')]`

Comment: I think the problem is you have set `sep="delimiter"`. Try setting `sep=","`. Happens your header is the whole first line now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the separator with option `sep=","` instead when reading the csv. The problem is you are reading a whole line as a header.

Means your should do:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"{}".format(path), header=6, sep=",", engine="python")
```

Then to drop the first column just do:

```
df = df.drop("Header=", axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you @Cedric Zoppolo this fixed the problem.